# How might I read (parse) html directly from a file using Watir?

Tags: html, ruby, file, parsing, watir

I can already do this with Nokogiri of course

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(src)
```

where src is a text column in my database.

But I really like Watir's search interface for developers over Nokogiri.

There's not much evidence on how to do this so far in my searches on the internet, viz. for unhosted html.

Answer (score 2):

You can access local html files by adding a "file://" to the start of the path to the file (see my [blog post on the topic](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/opening-local-html-files-with-watir-classic/)).

For example, lets say you have an html file on your computer at "C:\users\testuser\desktop\test_file.html".

If you want to open this file and interact with it using Watir, you can do:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('file://C:\users\testuser\desktop\test_file.html')
```

Then you can interact with the browser/page/html as you normally would with Watir.

Note: If you get a `NoMethodError: unknown property or method: 'document'` exception when trying to interact with the browser, make sure that your browser is being opened by a user with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work for you, you can try navigating with the driver directly like so:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new 
browser.driver.navigate.to('file://Users/path/to/file.html')
```

**PS I am on a mac, but this should work irrespective of your OS**